# Weird insert behavior with mysql and codeginiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, lastinsertid

I have a fairly simple insert statement

```
<...>
if (!empty($attributes)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `part_attrs` (`part_id`, `attr`, `type`, `list_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
            foreach($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                $this->db->query($sql, array($partid, $attribute[0], $attribute[1], $key));
                $attrid = $this->db->insert_id();
                echo $attrid.'<br />';

                if (strlen($attribute[2]) > 0) {
                    $values = explode(',', $attribute[2]);
                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `attr_values` (`attr_id`, `field_values`) VALUES (?, ?)';
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $this->db->query($sql, array($attrid, trim($value)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
<...>
```

The odd thing is only one or two of the rows are being inserted. I put that echo line in to see the row id's it was returning for each insert since I'm not getting any errors. If for example I insert three items it will return something like 18, 124, 128. Where the 18 id is the next and expected id so this row gets inserted and then the rest don't. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the value of `$sql` inside your second `if` statement. 124 and 128 is attributes from the `attr_values` table. Consider using another variable name inside your `if` statement, or move the first assignment to `$sql` inside the `foreach` loop (move it down one line).

Comment: Haha... yeah I just noticed that. Gotta love stupid mistakes. Thanks.